# Moving Magento core modules from app/code to vendor?

Tags: magento2, composer, vendor

**Magento 2.4.3**

I need to move the Magento core files which were installed in app/code/Magento by accident to the vendor folder so they can be updated with composer. Any advice on how to do that? Could not find much on Google.

I aleady tried deleting the content of the vendor folder and running `composer install` or `composer update`. That does not install what I need, only the current vendor state will be restored.

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get the files from GitHub? It would be best to install a fresh copy using composer and then copy all files back to this environment (please remember to keep a backup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best option would be creating a new project & install using composer
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/composer.html

After that, simply copy from your old project any relevant code in app/code & app/design folders & composer.json file

Comment: Some pages were built using the Magento PageBuilder, how would I move those? They are in the database ...

Comment: I was talking about code. You can use same database after that

Comment: Right, I will try :-)

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it helped